# Google Maps API Directions White Tiles Along Route

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, maps

Whenever I calculate a route everything works perfectly except for the path along the route is covered with white tiles.  I've been looking around the net and I couldn't seem to find a solution to my problem.  My guess is that there is something wrong with my js (although I am not getting any errors showing up in the console).  It would be much appreciated if you could shed some light on what may cause something like this to happen.  Thanks!! :).

Comment: if you think the problem is with your js, could you post some of what you believe is the offending portion?

Comment: Not a js problem.  HTML5 Boilerplate handheld.css got in the way.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that my handheld.css stylesheet was somehow adding those white boxes over the map.  All I had to do was edit out the background color from the following code:

```
* {
  float: none;       
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}
```

This may apply to anyone that is using html5 boilerplate so I thought I would share.  Thanks.